# Pre Populate Account name in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, button

How to Pre-populate account name using standard 'New' Button in related list.

Comment: I don't think you can using the standard new button. You could not even do that in classic. Unless i am misunderstanding you...

Comment: Thanks For your response
we can able to override the standard button using VF Page

Comment: Need to figure out some URL hack! In classic you can do only. In case you don't want to override.

Comment: @Satheesh - Right you can override it but then it is not the "Standard New Button" anymore lol.....

Comment: @Eric - Could you please guide me how to pre-populate parent account name while creating new record

Comment: @Satheesh - Unfortunately I am not in a position to be able to to do that as I have not done it before in LEX. I am in the same boat as you :) Since it seems like something so basic I am betting it is either not possible or will require a lot of work...at least that has been my experience so far lol

Comment: from standard hacks this is nott work. You need to create custom page for this.

Answer (score 0):

URL hack does not work in lightning! You will have to create a custom lightning component which will override the page for you if that is worth the efforts for the requirement!